# Mysqli only returns one value

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a while PHP statment which should print all question which like something

```
$full = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE question LIKE '%$question%'";
$fullQ = mysqli_query($conn, $full);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fullQ)) {
printf(nl2br("%s\n"), $row['question']);
}
```

But it prints only one result with utf-8
I've escaped the data but nothing

Comment: why it should print more?

Comment: What are your inputs? Have you checked that the database actually has more than one matching row?

Comment: Yes it has maaaaaany values with the same $question name

Comment: print out mysql_num_rows($fullQ) to make sure

Comment: I've checked something, It works perfectly with normal english data, but prints one value only when I use uft-8 value

Comment: @AhmedNezar Add what inputs you've tried and which ones are failing to the question.

Comment: I've inputed
**بم تفسر** and There is in the database
`بم تفسر عرض الرسول صلى الله عليه وسلم نفسه علي الوفود في موسم الحج
بم تفسر تسمية الشطوط بهذا الاسم 
بم تفسر تغطى الثلوج قمم الجبال العالية في وطننا العربي 
بم تفسر سعى قريش لمنع الرسول صلى الله عليه وسلم للحاق بالمسلمين 
بم تفسر تكليف الرسول لعامر بن فهيره برعى الاغنام حول غار ثور
بم تفسر ارسال الرسول لمصعب بن عمير مع اهل يثرب بعد بيعة العقبه الاولى `
  The database containts about 80 other data starts with بم تفسر
and each one starts with بم تفسر is a new row

Answer (score -1):

Have you try to put a real escape string before the $full?

```
$question = mysqli->real_escape_string($question);
$full = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE question LIKE '%$question%'";
$fullQ = mysqli_query($conn, $full);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fullQ)) {
    printf(nl2br("%s\n"), $row['question']);
}
```

Comment: Read about `fetch_row()`.